# How to change ajax-charset?

Tags: ajax, jquery, character-encoding, special-characters

How can I change the default encoding used by `$.post()`?

The arguments are encoded with UTF-8. How can I encode it with ISO 8859-1?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use:

```
contentType:"application/x-javascript; charset:ISO-8859-1"
```

Comment: You might need to add a `beforeSend`, too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14397845/92756

Answer (score 6):

By giving the content type explicitly during ajax call as below may allow you to override the default content type.

```
$.ajax({
        data: parameters,
        type: "POST",
        url: ajax_url,
        timeout: 20000,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-15",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: callback
});
```

You would also have to specify the charset on the server.

Ex: for php

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15'); ?>
```

I hope this may help you.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the charset cannot be changed anymore – [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) docs states:

> The W3C XMLHttpRequest specification dictates that the charset is
>   always UTF-8; specifying another charset will not force the browser to
>   change the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

See section 4.5.6.4.4.3 of the XHR spec:
https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-send()-method

> If contentTypeRecord is not failure, contentTypeRecord’s
>   parameters["charset"] exists, and parameters["charset"] is not an
>   ASCII case-insensitive match for "UTF-8", then:
>
> Set contentTypeRecord’s parameters["charset"] to "UTF-8".

The spec forces browsers to always send as UTF-8.

You may however, use the `fetch` API. Since it's not an XHR, posting using fetch will honour your encoding.

```js
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': `text/plain; charset=${yourCustomEncoding}`
  },
  body
}).then(...
```