# Jquery ignores encoding ISO-8859-1

Tags: javascript, jquery, character-encoding, content-type, iso-8859-1

I have a website which apperently removes the correct encoding (ISO-8859-1) from a string and sends it wrong.

I have this encoding specified in my HTML

```
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
```

I load my javascript via

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="ISO-8859-1" src="...
```

I send for Information via JQuery Ajax Request like this (with german special character 'ö' and 'ä'):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '..',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1',
    data: xmlRequest.html(),...
```

This is translated into a request and in the chrome developer tools I see this in the Request Header:

```
..
Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8
..
```

What happened there?

Of course the special characters are encoded wrong ("Ã¶" instead of "ö") the server can't understand me and i get an error.

Comment: you have to set your webservers header.. You cant do that with javascript. It's a serverside feature.

Answer (score 34):

Because I had the same problem, I'll provide a solution that worked for me. Background: Microsoft Excel is too stupid to export a CSV-File in charset UTF-8:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '...',
    contentType: 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1',
    // This is the imporant part!!!
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
        jqXHR.overrideMimeType('text/html;charset=iso-8859-1');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this!

Comment: How do you do this without jquery, directly with a `XMLHttpRequest()`?

Comment: Does this actually send the request also? Mine won't 'post' after adding this :(

Comment: Yes it should. You sure your code gets even executed?

Comment: Its not working for me. I want to send some data to another page via POST but it seens like the POST variables aren't sent

Answer (score 8):

According to the [`jQuery.ajax()` `contentType` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> Data will always be transmitted to the server using UTF-8 charset; you must decode this appropriately on the server side."

Comment: Is this a Jquery-Thing or Ajax in general?

Comment: According to that same documentation page, "POST data will always be transmitted to the server using UTF-8 charset, per the W3C XMLHTTPRequest standard."