# How to load ISO-8859-1 content via AJAX in jQueryMobile 1.3.1 with correct character encoding?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, encoding

I have got a PHP script (CMS) which generates ISO-8859-1 content (in the background there is also a database with Latin1 data).
To visualize the data on mobile devices I use jQuery Mobile 1.3.1. In general there is no problem with character encoding if you use the correct meta tag in your HTML:

```
<meta charset="iso-8859-1" />
```

However jQuery Mobile has got this default setting:

```
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = true;
```

So jQuery Mobile will automatically handle link clicks and form submissions through Ajax, when possible.

This is a very smart feature, but it destroys some special characters like german umlaute and you get this nasty characters: �

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 uses on default UTF-8 on ajax requests.
There are different solutions to solve the problem:

1. Disable Ajax for specific links, which redirect to content with special characters:

   ```
   data-ajax="false"
   ```
2. Turn off completely the ajax preloading feature:

   ```
   $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
   ```
3. Follow this [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14397845/1119695) and manually set the correct content type and override the mime type:

   ```
   $.ajaxSetup({
     contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1',
     beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
       jqXHR.overrideMimeType('application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1');
     }
   });
   ```

The last solution did work for me.

Comment: An old thread but it saved my day! Two days of dealing with this problem and the answer I found was downvoted by someone! I would upvote twice if I could! Thanks you!!!