# Convert ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8

Tags: javascript, jquery, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I am sending a HTTP request through jQuery's ajax.

But the server, which I have no access, returns ISO-8859-1 and I my page is UTF-8.

How can I convert the characters to be readable?

For without converting appears something like: it�rio

@Edit:
I've tried changing the charset of ajax requests using:

```
$.ajax({ contentType: ... });
```

And I tried to change the meta of the html to ISO-8859-1.

@Solution:
I've found the solution on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14397845/3451442

Comment: @mplungjan i already search. but i need convert from ISO-8859-1

Comment: Can you try   `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-1",` or   `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",` (not sure which way it converts)

Comment: @mplungjan i've tried that too and don't work. i need a function like iconv =/

Comment: @mplungjan sorry i'll edit post.

Answer (score 11):

Try the trick shown in: [How do I convert special UTF-8 chars to their iso-8859-1 equivalent using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396560/how-do-i-convert-special-utf-8-chars-to-their-iso-8859-1-equivalent-using-javasc)

in your case you could simply use:

```
utfstring = unescape(encodeURIComponent(ajaxreturn));
```

Edit: if this does not work either, try the other way round:

```
fixedstring = decodeURIComponent(escape(ajaxreturn));
```

It might also help if you post the output of the "encode" functions - this way its possible to identify what's going on:

```
encodeURIComponent(ajaxreturn)
        vs.
escape(ajaxreturn)
```

If none of these work I guess you should convert your whole page to be iso-8859-1:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

Comment: It did not work well. 
The content was: it�rio 
Was: itï¿½rio

Comment: Try `decodeURIComponent(ajaxreturn.replace(/\\x/g,"%"))`, it works for me.