# Chrome extension ajax sending malformed accented characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am sending an AJAX POST request using jQuery on a chrome extension but the data doesn't arrive as expected, accented characters turn out malformed.

The text "HÄGERSTEN" becomes "HÃ„GERSTEN".

The text appears fine in the console etc, only via AJAX to this other page it appears as mentioned. My AJAX call is basic, I send a data-object via jQuery $.ajax. I've tried both with and without contentType, UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1. No difference.

This is how I make my AJAX call:

```
var newValues = {name: 'HÄGERSTEN'}

$.ajax({
    url: POST_URL,
    type: 'POST',
    data: newValues,
    success: function() ...
});
```

The `newValues` object has more values but I retrieve them from a form. However, I have tried to specify these values manually as `newValues['name'] = 'ÄÄÄÄ';` and still would cause the same problem.

The original form element of the page that I am sending the AJAX to contains attribute `accept-charset="iso-8859-1"`. Maybe this matters.

The target website is using `Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1`. Just incase it might make a difference.

I assume this is an encoding issue and as I've understood it should be because Chrome extensions require the script files to be UTF-8 encoded which probably conflicts with the website the plugin is running on and the target AJAX page (same website) which is using an ISO-8859-1 encoding, however I have no idea how to deal with it. I have tried several methods of decoding/encoding it to and from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 and other tricks with no success.

I have tried using `encodeURIComponent` on my values which only makes them show that way exactly on the form that displays the values I have sent via POST, as e.g. `H%C3%84GERSTEN`.

I have no access to the websites server and cannot tell you whether this is a problem from their side, however I would not suppose so.

**UPDATE**

Now I have understood POST data must be sent as UTF-8! So a conversion is not the issue?

Comment: Well, those aren't `Latin` characters, but I digress. Can you show some relevant code? Maybe there's something wrong. My initial guess would be that the server expects `%`-encoded data which you can ontain via `encodeURIComponent` before sending.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes I have tried that. Updated question to answer you. What would I call them if not latin then?

Comment: `Accented characters` is probably the most unambiguous term I saw. As for the problem: [Jquery ignores encoding ISO-8859-1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14397845)

Comment: As I'm sending POST data, I assume that is no option. Tried it and no success. Quoting: `Data will always be transmitted to the server using UTF-8 charset; you must decode this appropriately on the server side.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it could have been solved using POST-data and AJAX. Perhaps if I made a pure JavaScript XHR AJAX call, I might be able to send POST-data encoded the way I like. I have no idea.

However, in my desperation I tried my final option (or what seemed like it); send the request as GET-data. I was lucky and the target page accepted GET-data.

Obviously the problem still persisted as I was sending data the same way, being UTF-8 encoded. So instead of sending the data as an object I parsed the data into a URL friendly string with my own function using `escape`, making sure they are ISO-8859-1 friendly (as `encodeURIComponent` encodes the URI as UTF-8 while `escape` encodes strings making them compatible with ISO-8859-1).

The simple function that cured my headaches:

```
function URLEncodeISO(values) {
   var params = [];
   for(var k in values) params[params.length] = escape(k) + '=' + escape(values[k]);
   return params.join('&');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the data is UTF-8 encoded when it is sent and not properly decoded on the server side. It has to be decoded on the server side. Test it out with the following encode and decode functions:

```js
function encode_utf8(s) {
  return unescape(encodeURIComponent(s));
}

function decode_utf8(s) {
  return decodeURIComponent(escape(s));
}

var encoded_string = encode_utf8("HÄGERSTEN");
var decoded_string = decode_utf8(encoded_string);
document.getElementById("encoded").innerText = encoded_string;
document.getElementById("decoded").innerText = decoded_string;
```

```html
<div>
Encoded string: <span id="encoded"></span>
</div>
<div>
Decoded string: <span id="decoded"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I have done so, not working. Encode simply only makes the text appear with the encoding (as mentioned in my main post) and decode throws error `malformed string` or so.

Answer (score 2):

We too faced the same situation but in our case we always sent the parameters using `JSON.stringify`.
For this you have to make changes, 
1) While making call to the page via AJAX you have to add `content-type` tag defining in which encoding data is sent

```
$.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: POST_URL,
        dataType: 'json',//In our case the datatype is JSON
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(newValues),//I always use parameters to be sent in JSON format
```

**EDIT**
After reading your question more clearly I came to know that your server side JSP uses `ISO-8859-1` encoding and reading some posts, I came to know that all [`POST` method data will be transmitted using `UTF-8`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) as mentioned.

> POST data will always be transmitted to the server using UTF-8 charset, per the W3C XMLHTTPRequest standard

But while reading post [jquery-ignores-encoding-iso-8859-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553463/jquery-ajax-character-encoding) there was a workaround posted by `iappwebdev` which might be useful and help you,

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '...',
    contentType: 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1',
    // This is the imporant part!!!
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
        jqXHR.overrideMimeType('text/html;charset=iso-8859-1');
    }
});
```

Above code is taken from [Code Posted by `iappwebdev`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988573/jquery-ignores-encoding-iso-8859-1/14397845#14397845)

Comment: JSON is no option as the target site is not mine and I cannot control the data type they accept. I am sending POST-data to emulate a form.

Comment: @Colandus It was example from my side you can remove the ` JSON.stringify` in your case

Comment: @Colandus just see if the edited answer solves your problem

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, however I have come up with a solution. I have posted it as an answer. I had already previously tried what you mentioned with no success.

Answer (score 1):

The client side character coding is not completely up to you (immagine the usage of the page from different users all around the world: chinese, italian...) while on the server side you need to handle the coding for your purposes.

So, the data in the Ajax-POST can continue to be UTF8-encoded, but in your server side  you coan to do the following:

PHP:

$name = utf8_decode($_POST['name']);

JSP:

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
String name = request.getParameter("name");
```

Comment: I understand that. Though I'm no expert in encodings and am not entirely sure what exactly is going on there. Thus I would like to know why my letter becomes as mentioned and hopefully get a solution or workaround for my problem.

Comment: @Colandus I understood you need help, so I suggested to separate the client and server side. Work only on server side. If you use php or jsp you could try my proposals. There is no trick to apply, it's only a matter regarding how do you handle character encoding on server side and if you do not want change it you can in any case force the reading of the parameters like I suggested to you. For more detailed answer I need your source code on server side related to the ajax call so that I can change it and propose the right solution. In any case I suggets you to take a look to your server side.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't phrase that properly. I don't have access to the server side. It's a Chrome extension I'm making which is passing POST-data to a website not in my control, emulating a form. It may be that their server is converting my value. Either way, I'm looking for a way to pass my value and still get it right.

Comment: @Colandus Now it's more clear to me....It's not simple because if you have on client side for instance the classical italian è it will be handled differently on your server. Can you investigate which type of encoding uses your server page? I know it's hard, but I think this may be a path to follow.