# How to force XMLHttpRequest to use ISO-8859-1 charset only?

Tags: javascript, ajax, encoding

I have ISO-8859-1 database, so I like to exchange requests entirely in this codepage. So, how to set content-type for AJAX requests in the right way?

Comment: You're asking for trouble down the road. UTF-8 end-to-end or die!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change ajax-charset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285936/how-to-change-ajax-charset)

Comment: Yes, I actually can convert it when it comes to the server. But I want it in the "right" way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX Character Encoding Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553463/jquery-ajax-character-encoding-problem)

Comment: I appreciate a comment added when downvoting.

Comment: Actually I have non-UTF (one byte) database in the backend, so the question remains very important.

Comment: @Thevs this is exactly the wrong way, you are trusting the client to send data in certain encoding but they can in fact send arbitrary data to your server. A robust server will check the encoding for validity and do conversion or reject.

Comment: @Esailija: "but they can in fact send arbitrary data to your server" - no, they can't.

Comment: Also, - what encoding has to do with data sent unchecked to the server?!

Comment: @Thevs well what is preventing them? If a browser can connect to your server and send well-formed data, what is going to prevent someone from sending anything they want?

Comment: @Esailija: Browser app has an unique session number. This is checked on the server side.

Comment: That was a rhetorical question, there is absolutely no way your server can know whether a client is a normal user with a browser or someone using tools that can more easily send any data to server. You cannot trust the client even if you're a game server using proprietary protocols let alone an open one like HTTP.

Comment: Stop please talking about SQL injections and (probably) PHP. I have non-SQL database and don't use PHP. My question is not about sanitizing input.

Comment: What a people!? I know about all these issues, but I asked completely different question.

Comment: thgis is old but for anyone stumbling on this, use the *.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1');* method of the xmlhttprequest object from [MDN Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though it's bad to do (bunch of comments above), this would work:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.open("GET", path, false);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1')
```

If you are using jQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/a/553572/2527433

Comment: Oops, typo, fixed now.

Comment: The `charset` parameter is illegal for this content type and some servers even reject requests as malformed if they do. It also makes no sense as valid content in this content-type uses only ASCII.

Comment: Sending the charset along with application/<something> is not recommended. Lots of APIs are NOT accepting multiple settings in `Content-type` header.

Answer (score 1):

According to the W3C spec for [XMLHttpRequest.send()](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send%28%29-method), the charset will end up being UTF-8 in almost all cases, depending on the value of *data*. Even any charset encoding you specify will likely be overwritten with UTF-8:

> If a Content-Type header is in author request headers and its value is a valid MIME type that has a charset parameter whose value is not a case-insensitive match for *encoding*, and *encoding* is not null, set all the charset parameters of that Content-Type header to *encoding*.

There is some wiggle-room for the User Agent to determine the encoding: set the AJAX-containing page's encoding to ISO-8859-1.  The UA will then assume ISO for all form submission (unless the form otherwise specifies a different encoding) and likely AJAX submission, depending on interpretation of the W3C algorithm.

Ultimately, the only reliable solution is to set the page the visitor sees (with the AJAX on it) to ISO-8859-1, and then make sure to check it and convert to ISO on the back-end (you **need to be sanitizing all user input before sending it to the database anyway**, so just add this conversion to the process).  There are plenty of library functions to do this in PHP or your given language.  There's no way to guarantee conformance with the specs otherwise, so absolutely check/ensure the encoding on the back-end.

Comment: This answer doesn't help me. My page is set to ISO-8859-1, but, anyway, all AJAX requests go with UTF-8.

Comment: I don't need sanitizing. Dot.

Answer (score 0):

I think I need to explain encoding and the charset parameter. These concern how the raw bytes
sent over the network should be decoded.

For example, consider the content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and the following data:

```
0x61253344254345254232
```

Because there was no charset (in fact, charset is illegal parameter for this content type...) ISO-8859-1
must be assumed. So decoding the above in ISO-8859-1 results:

```
"a%3D%CE%B2"
```

Now there is another format to decode (form urlencoded) which has its own rules. [The current specs say
that the percent encoding here must be UTF-8](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm), so after doing *string* -> *string* transformation you get
from the above:

```
"a=ß"
```

So as you can see, the format never uses characters other than ASCII so the charset doesn't really matter and
is not supported anyway.

---

Your actual problem is unrelated to what encoding the percent encoding uses. Even if you defined a custom function that percent-encodes
in ISO-8859-1, the server would still have to decode it on arrival and encode it for the database. You have
nothing to gain from this.