# Ajax charset vs Form submit charset

Tags: javascript, ajax, character-encoding

Back in the good old days, the ajax charset was always the same as the charset of the page.  Now it looks like the charset is ALWAYS utf8 and it's impossible to change it.

Whereas, the standard form.submit() uses the same Accept-Charset as the page.

Is it true that you cannot change the Accept-Charset of an ajax post any longer?  If's is possible, how can it be done in Chrome--via javascript and not command line args.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906904/how-to-force-xmlhttprequest-to-use-iso-8859-1-charset-only

Comment: I've tired this, I do not think it works in chrome.  At least I cannot make it work. I've been testing using 'POST', this example is using 'GET'-- I will try it as a GET.

Comment: I must be using some messed up ajax code some where, the code in the post you gave does work.

Comment: @adeneo I take that back.  As soon as the post body added: `xhr.send(postBody)`, the content type is forced to UTF8