# How to change character encoding on XMLHttpRequest upon sending FormData Object

Tags: javascript, php, encoding, utf-8

I need to change my character encoding to `EUC-JP` 

Here is my code:

```
formData.append("send", "送信");
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "foo.php", false);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/html; charset=euc-jp");
xhr.send(formData);
```

I've just learned that:

> **`Content-Type`** cannot be set upon sending ***FormData()*** object.

and

> the default encoding is **`UTF-8`**

Because of `UTF-8` encoding, I cannot receive the correct japanese characters on ***foo.php***.

Comment: Why not use UTF8 everywhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force XMLHttpRequest to use ISO-8859-1 charset only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906904/how-to-force-xmlhttprequest-to-use-iso-8859-1-charset-only)

Comment: UTF-8 should support the four groups of japanese characters, as long as it's used consistently

Comment: @Tareq I think not? because of the sending _**FormData()**_ object part.

Comment: @mplungjan my whole project is `EUC-JP`, Im using japanese characters in different forms.

Comment: @neil have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22529662/5436486