# Data is UTF-8, Ajax is returning some characters incorrectly

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, utf-8, utf8mb4

I have spent a lot of time searching the web and seeing a lot of similar answers, but cannot find anything that works for my situation.

I spent some time converting my MySQL database to UTF-8 from latin1 (the default). I emptied the tables (truncate), and re-imported the data from a text file. I have set the headers for my pages to use the meta tag to UTF-8:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8" />
```

And that's being used everywhere. When I read data via PHP and output it into forms, and such, the data appears correctly, text like: Königstadt appear as one might hope. Saving them (update set ...) they seem to be okay, because when I re-read them from the data the display in the form is correct. (The display in PHP Admin shows "KÃ¶nigstadt", which is weird, but when I read the data it seems to be correct ... -- I am hoping this is some oddity of PHPAdmin)

Where everything seems to be falling down on me is my Ajax code, when I retrieve data via PHP using Ajax. The following is a relatively simple routine that calls a PHP program to generate the option tags for an SELECT:

```
     function get_branches()
     {
        // numeric values that need to be passed to the
        // routine (so we show the correct item selected)
        var region = document.getElementById("search_region").value;
        // the code in load_branches needs this, but ...
        var branch = document.getElementById("search_branch").value;

        $.ajax
        ({
           type: "POST",
           url: "<?php echo $Roster_html_RootPath; ?>lookups/load_branches.php",
           data: {
                   'region' : region,
                   'local_branch' : branch
                 },
           //cache: false,
           success: function(data)
           {
              // load contents of DIV tag with id of branchoptions:
              $("#branch_options").html(data);
           }  // end success
        }); // end ajax call
     }; // end function get_branches()

  }); // end document.ready ...
```

Most of the records returned are fine. However the one shown above (Königstadt) looks like: KÃ¶nigstadt in the HTML Select that is returned.

I have been trying to find a solution, such as setting contentType for Ajax, here are things I have tried:

```
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
```

This one doesn't seem to make any difference at all. Nothing changes.

```
contentType: "application/text; charset=utf-8",
```

(or application/json)
This kills the values being passed to the PHP file -- the data array doesn't seem to get there, because I get errors from PHP:

```
Notice: Undefined index: region in C:\xampp\htdocs\Heralds\Roster\lookups\load_branches.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined index: local_branch in C:\xampp\htdocs\Heralds\Roster\lookups\load_branches.php on line 33
```

I am at a complete loss how to return the values correctly. I need versions for both text or html (where I return an html table or the option tags as here), but I also need to use the json array for some of my code to return the values correctly. None of them seem to work properly with UTF-8 encoded data. I have been working on this for some time now, and am very frustrated. The explanations I am seeing are not working or in some cases not making sense ...

**PHP `lookups/load_branches.php`**

```
<?php
// if session has not started:
session_start();

// load some basic configuration, including relative paths
// and variables needed ...
include_once( "../includes/configuration.php" );

// data connection
include_once( $Roster_RootPath . "includes/connect.php");

// values from Ajax code:
$region       = $_POST["region"];
$local_branch = $_POST["local_branch"];

// open the roster_branches table and get list
if( $region > 0 ) // check only needed for find_by_branch.php
{
   $branch_statement = "select * from roster_branches where region=" .  $region . " order by local";
}
else
{
   $branch_statement = "select * from roster_branches order by local";
}

// first, get the data from the table:
$branch_result = mysqli_query( $connect, $branch_statement );
if( !$branch_result )
{
   $out = "";
   $out .= "<div class='alert alert-danger'>";
   $out .= "<p><b>Error in SQL statement ...</b><br />";
   $errornum = mysqli_errno( $connect );
   $out .= "MySQL Error Number: " . $errornum . "<br />";
   $out .= "MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error( $connect ) . "<br />";
   $out .= "SQL Statement: " . $branch_statement . "</p>";
   $out .= "</div>";
   echo $out;
   die;   
}
else
{
   $out = "";
   // create select:
   $out = "<select class='form-control' id='local_branch' name='local_branch'>\n";

   // need the blank option:
   $out .= "   <option value=0 selected></option>\n";

   while( $branch_row = mysqli_fetch_array( $branch_result ) )
   {
      $id = $branch_row["rb_id"];
      $local = $branch_row["local"];
      $selected = "";
      if( $local_branch == $id )
      {
         $selected = " selected";
      }
      $out .= "<option value=" . $id . $selected . ">" . $local . "</option> \n";
   }

   $out .= "</select>\n";
   echo $out;      
} // we have something

?>
```

Comment: Please show your PHP file `lookups/load_branches.php`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Will add the load_branches.php file, it's not too long, but need to make sure the editor formats it properly ...

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285936/how-to-change-ajax-charset

Comment: From the sample pointed to by @Martin:
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
Has no effect;
contentType:"application/x-javascript; charset:UTF-8",
Breaks the code (it does not pass the data array to the PHP file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my MySQL database to UTF-8 from latin1 (the default).

---

> 1) I used "utf8_unicode_ci". 2) I have no idea what "multibyte safe functions" you're talking about. I use mysqli_real_escape_string() when reading data from $_POST, and the usual mysqli_query() and so on functions

This is the cause of your issue.

There are 3 main places to work to correct this:

## 1)

You need to enable true UTF-8 (*4-byte*) in MySQL so that data stored in your SQL is *stored* as the correct UTF-8 characters. by **universally** using collations and character sets with the `utf8mb4_` prefix.

## 2)

To ensure data from your application/PHP is *saved* correctly you then need to ensure that the data is *passed to MySQL as UTF-8 4-byte characters* by setting the **connection character set** to full (*4-byte*) UTF-8  in your PHP:

```
$mysqliObject->set_charset('utf8mb4');   // object oriented style
mysqli_set_charset($connect, 'utf8mb4');    // procedural code style
```

## 3)

Finally; you need to ensure that any processing PHP does with the resulting data is **multi-byte aware**; by using the [`mbstring`](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mbstring.php) set of functions.

Most notably:

- [`mb_http_output()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-http-output.php) — Detect and convert HTTP output character encoding
- [`mb_internal_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php) — Set PHP's  internal character encoding

So your top of each PHP page should look like this before any browser output)

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
```

Then if you do anything with `str_<whatever>` functions (and some others) you know it won't break you strings before they're output to the browser (ajx in this case).

---

- If you can't use `mbstring` functions for any reason then check out here [how to install them](http://www.knowledgebase-script.com/kb/article/how-to-enable-mbstring-in-php-46.html
  ).
- Please also review [this excellent Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) has helped you at all?
- Further reading about solving the MySQL side of things [can be found here](https://medium.com/@manish_demblani/breaking-out-from-the-mysql-character-set-hell-24c6a306e1e5).

Comment: 1) I used "utf8_unicode_ci". 
2) I have no idea what "multibyte safe functions" you're talking about. I use mysqli_real_escape_string() when reading data from $_POST, and the usual mysqli_query() and so on functions.

Comment: I tried inserting that into some code, and got an error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mbstring() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Heralds\Roster\lookups\load_branches.php on line 79

Comment: @KenMayer I have written a more useful answer for you,. I hope this helps

Comment: @KenMayer `mbstring` is not a function in itself. Please refer to the manual.

Comment: utf8 is fine for simple characters like ö. utf8mb4 really only becomes necessary when dealing with things like emoji that are at much higher codepoints.

Comment: @miken32 yes but somewhere along the line the charset is being abused --  If mbstring is not enabled on the server (unknown at preset) then PHPMyAdmin may output things incorrected

Comment: I added:
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
Before reading (querying the $_POST array) the data, nothing happened, no changes in behavior.

Comment: Converting the database to utf8mb4 _may_ have done the trick. I have to do more testing, but the two programs in question are returning the correct values at this time.

Comment: It appears that:
1) converting to utf8mb4, and; 2) using the mb_...() functions may have resolved this issue. I have tested on two different tables and two very different sets of code, doing different things and it seems to work at the moment.

Comment: Oh, this: `mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8mb4');`  -- seems to mess things up (and it's not the name of the connection string, but the data seems to get converted yet again ...)

Comment: @KenMayer glad it solved it, re your last comment, you need to adapt my code to your own specific situation ; ie use the varible name you have used for your MySQL connection object `;-)`

Comment: @Martin -- I did that (changed the connection object name), it still messed up data in my application. Thanks, though.

Comment: @KenMayer have you read the manual for [`mysql_set_charset`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)?

Comment: @Martin - I looked it over, but after a certain point my eyes started to glaze over. Most of these manuals are not easy to read. I don't understand why I need this, when everything else seems to be working, and if I use it, my pages seem to be doing some sort of translation of the characters making them unreadable on the screen; however, if I leave that out, they look fine.

Answer (score 0):

`Ã¶` is "Mojibake" for `ö`.  See "Mojibake" in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) .

But the real problem probably happen when you converted from latin1.

The tables needed to be converted via `ALTER TABLE .. CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.  Any other technique is likely to make a mess.

Any connection to MySQL needs to be specify `utf8mb4`.