# jQuery AJAX doesn't set charset encoding

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "post",
    url: $('#tForm').attr('action'),
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=windows-1250",
    data: $('#tForm').serialize()
})
```

But upon request when I check passed headers I can see some default value:

```
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
```

How to pass this correctly?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285936/how-to-change-ajax-charset

Comment: Note: *The W3C XMLHttpRequest specification dictates that the charset is always UTF-8; specifying another charset will not force the browser to change the encoding.* Might try Headers or `fetch()` alternative.

Comment: @Twisty The accepted answer there says to do what he's doing.